# Synchronization of access to a file on a per-file basis

Tags: java, file, concurrency

I'm writing a server-side program that logs events on a per-user basis. I have the following code to do this :

```
public void logUser(long uniqueID, String event) throws IOException
{
    BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(uniqueID + ".log", true));
    buffWriter.write(event);
    buffWriter.close();
}
```

Now as multiple different events may be called on the same user from different threads in a small difference of time, I'd like to synchronize this process on a per-user basis. This is because the files used are unique per user.

I'd like to know the most efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Use a log framework perhaps?

Comment: I'd rather stick to standard Java unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Java has a standard logging interface. Logging is just not one of those things you should attempt to reinvent unless you a) want to learn how to write a logging framework or b) have some exceptionally unique requirements (which you do not appear to have).

Comment: @Hele not using a logging framework when this is exactly what you need is going to be painful.

Comment: Did not know that. Could you perhaps point me to some resource which could serve my needs?

Comment: @Paolo Perhaps you meant _not_ attempt to reinvent?

Comment: Can u be more specific :

Comment: More specific? I dont understand..

Comment: Just synchronize the method. If you don't wanna lock using the current instance, create your own lock instance to use

Comment: @VinceEmigh That would cause a major performance bottleneck and is against the point of my question.

Comment: Javadoc is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html but I would strongly recommend looking at SLF4J and Logback instead of the standard library.

Comment: Your code will leak resources if the `write` throws an exception.

Answer (score 4):

I can't recommend rewriting a logging framework because it is much more complicated than it sounds and you would almost certainly be better off using an existing one. See for example [Java Logging vs Log4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840/java-logging-vs-log4j) and [Why not use java.util.logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359187/why-not-use-java-util-logging) for various alternatives.

However for your use case you could use a `ConcurrentHashMap` of locks:

```
ConcurrentMap<Long, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<> ();

public void logUser(long uniqueID, String event) throws IOException {
  Object lock = locks.computeIfAbsent(uniqueID, i -> new Object());
  synchronized(lock) {
    try (BufferedWriter buffWriter =
                 new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(uniqueID + ".log", true));) {
      buffWriter.write(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe an alternative to synchronizing the whole thing is to use an async approach. Let's say that all of the log entries are added to a `BlockingQueue` and some other thread consumes the queue. Then, no synchronization is needed.

Example:

```
public class LogAsync {
    // Some kind of abstraction for a log entry
    public static class LogEntry {
        private final String event;
        private final long uniqueId;

        public LogEntry(long uniqueId, String event) {
            this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
            this.event = event;
        }

        public String getEvent() {
            return event;
        }

        public long getUniqueId() {
            return uniqueId;
        }
    }

    // A blocking queue where the entries are stored    
    private final BlockingQueue<LogEntry> logEvents = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    // Adds a log entry to the blocking queue    
    public void logUser(long uniqueID, String event) {
        logEvents.add(new LogEntry(uniqueID, event));
    }

    // Starts the thread that handles the "writing to file"
    public LogAsync start() {
        // Run in another thread
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            final LogEntry entry = logEvents.take();

                            try (BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(entry.getUniqueId() + ".log", true))) {
                                buffWriter.write(entry.getEvent());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        return this;
    }
}
```

The way you could initialize the whole thing could be like this:

```
final LogAsync logger = new LogAsync().start();
logger.logUser(1, "Hello");
logger.logUser(1, "there");
logger.logUser(2, "Goodbye");
```

So, this is basically an alternative to synchronizing the whole thing. Note that this code is sample code only and there are some modifications that must be taken to make production-worthy. E.g., there must be a nice way to shutdown the writer-thread.

However, my recommendation is to **not** use a synchronized or asynchronous approach. Instead, **use a logging framework** such as [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void logUser(long uniqueID, String event) throws IOException
{
    synchronized(Long.valueOf(uniqueID)) {
        BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(uniqueID + ".log", true));
        buffWriter.write(event);
        buffWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting. But doesn't synchronized work on Objects themselves and not their values?

Comment: Precisely, Long.valueOf(long x) give you wrapper object of primitive long x.

Comment: Such a synchronization would require `Long.valueOf` to always provide the same object for the same primitive argument, which isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @E_net4 That was my question exactly.

Comment: `synchronized(Long.valueOf(uniqueID).toString().intern()) {
       BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new     ileWriter(uniqueID + ".log", true));
             buffWriter.write(event);
             buffWriter.close();
         }`